# Mathematical operation of CHARACTER [not numeric] in php

Tags: php, variables, data-structures

is there any way to sum/substrate character in php?

For example if

```
$var1 = 'a';
$var2 = 'b';
$var3 = 'a';

$calculation = $var1 - $var2 + $var3;

echo $calculation;
```

I want the output as `2a-b`

Just like we did in high school algebra?

Comment: No, PHP does not include a built-in Mathematica.

Comment: oops! I wish I could :(

Comment: and i wish i could code naked supermodels in php

Comment: @Dagon What have you tried so far? Show us some code ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a simple function to make something like what you want.
It's just an example, you will have to improve it a lot if you really want to use it, but is a good start.

Limitations:
Only works with letters (Won't work propely if you add numbers, you will have to add that functionaliy).

ALL the letters must have their plus or minus.

You must use spaces before a plus or minus.

This is definitely not the best way to do it, as I said you have to improve it. I wrote it fast but I tested it a bit.

```
<?
function calc($str){
    $data = preg_split("/ /", $str);
    $used = Array();
    $buffer = "";
    foreach ($data as $pos=>$letter){
        foreach ($data as $pos2=>$letter2){
            if ($letter[1] == $letter2[1] && !in_array($pos, $used) && !in_array($pos2, $used) && $pos != $pos2){
                $first = $letter[0] == '+' ? 1 : -1;
                $second = $letter2[0] == '+' ? 1 : -1;
                $buffer .= ($first+$second).$letter[1];
                $used[count($used)] = $pos;
                $used[count($used)] = $pos2;
            }
        }
    }
    foreach ($data as $pos=>$letter){
        if (!in_array($pos, $used)){
            $buffer .= $letter;
        }
    }
    return $buffer;
}
echo calc("+a -b +a");
?>
```

Output:

```
2a-b
```